# webform alter default value template.php

Tags: 6, webforms

I need to alter the default value of a webform in d6, so in my template.php I insert the following function, but it does not work; I don't like to use `$get` in webform.

```
function themename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ('webform_client_form_id' == $form_id) {
    $form['id_of_input']['#default_value'] = $node->field_cck_value[0]['value'];
    return $form;
  }
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Webform is a node module. So editing a node even though it contains form can be altered using [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6).

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$form['submitted']['id_of_input']['#default_value'] = $node->field_cck_value[0]['value'];
```

For further details, refer http://drupal.org/node/1558246